# How to make the animation smooth in the below SVG?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Im trying to make the below svg animation smooth. I would want to make the white gradient to move through the path indefinitely. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```html
<svg width="8" height="243" viewBox="0 0 8 243" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M3 3L3 240" stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" strokeWidth="5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"/>
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="3" y1="3" x2="3" y2="240" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0" stopColor="#E8FF00" stopOpacity="1">
                            <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="1;1;1;0;0;0.5;0.8;1;1;1;1;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="0.3" stopColor="#E8FF00" stopOpacity="0">
                            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0.3;0.2;0.1;0;1;0.9;0.8;0.7;0.6;0.5;0.4;0.3" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="0.4" stopColor="#E8FF00" stopOpacity="0">
                            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0.4;0.3;0.2;0.1;0;1;0.9;0.8;0.7;0.6;0.5;0.4" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="0.5" stopColor="#E8FF00" stopOpacity="0">
                            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0.5;0.4;0.3;0.2;0.1;0;1;0.9;0.8;0.7;0.6;0.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="1" stopColor="#E8FF00" stopOpacity="1">
                            <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="1;1;1;1;0.8;0.5;0;0;0;1;1;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
                        </stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
            </svg>
```

Comment: use stop-color instead of stop-color and stop-opacity instead of stopColor and stopOpacity

Comment: i was using react so i had to convert them to react way of passing attributes to avoid warnings. My bad had to paste the code in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider solving a gradient animation using [gradientTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientTransform)

Below is the code showing the position of the white bar in the static version

```html
<svg width="108" height="243" viewBox="0 0 108 243" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            
     <rect x="3" y="3" width="5" rx="5" height="240" fill="url(#paint0_linear)" /> 
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"" >
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="43%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="57%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="grey" />
                             
    </linearGradient>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Add an animation command to move the entire gradient from top to bottom
`<animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform" ... />`

```html
<svg width="108" height="243" viewBox="0 0 108 243" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            
     <rect x="3" y="3" width="5" rx="5" height="240" fill="url(#paint0_linear)" /> 
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="43%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="57%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="grey" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 -1"
        to="0 1"
        begin="0s"
        dur="1.5s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
 </svg>
```

## Update

@tejash jl comments:

> animationTransform is not working on line path

I changed your path a little

```html
<svg width="108" height="243" viewBox="0 0 108 243" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M3 3L3 240 L6 240 L6 3z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>  
     
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="43%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="57%" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="grey" />
     <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 -1"
        to="0 1"
        begin="0s"
        dur="1.5s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                                                
    </linearGradient>
 </defs> 
    
</svg>
```

The path must be closed for the gradient animation to work. But you can also select a polyline and apply a gradient to the line

```html
<svg width="108" height="243" viewBox="0 0 108 243" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <polyline points="3,3 3,240" stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="5"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>    
     
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="3" y1="3" x2="3" y2="240" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset=".43" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset=".50" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset=".57" stop-color="grey" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="grey" />
     <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 -240"
        to="0 240"
        begin="0s"
        dur="1.5s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                                                
    </linearGradient>
 </defs> 
    
</svg>
```

Comment: animationTransform is not working on line path.